# App crashes when trying to take and rename picture

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm trying to create a button that opens the camera and take a picture then rename this picture. I searched for the code and I found one, but when I recall the onClick method, the app crashes ..

Camera code

```
        // Capture Image code
    Button savePicture = findViewById(R.id.act_edit_capture_image);
savePicture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {

        //camera stuff
        Intent imageIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyy_HHmmss").format(new Date());

        //folder stuff
        File dir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES + " Soleya");


         File image = new File(dir, "Sol_" + actId + "_" + timeStamp + ".jpg");
        Uri imageUri  = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
                EditActivity.this,
                "com.example.mustafa.progressupdate.provider", //(use your app signature + ".provider" )
                image);

        imageIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri );
        startActivityForResult(imageIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);

    }
});
```

The crash log

```
    --------- beginning of crash
09-12 23:46:22.387 23677-23677/com.example.mustafa.progressupdate E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.mustafa.progressupdate, PID: 23677
    java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE flg=0x3 cmp=com.android.camera2/com.android.camera.CaptureActivity clip={text/uri-list U:content://com.example.mustafa.progressupdate.provider/external_files/Pictures%20Soleya/Sol_A22430_120918_234622.jpg} (has extras) } from ProcessRecord{ae97546 23677:com.example.mustafa.progressupdate/u0a94} (pid=23677, uid=10094) with revoked permission android.permission.CAMERA
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1683)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1636)
        at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startActivity(ActivityManagerNative.java:3071)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1518)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4224)
        at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityApi16.startActivityForResult(BaseFragmentActivityApi16.java:54)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:68)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4183)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:744)
        at com.example.mustafa.progressupdate.EditActivity$7.onClick(EditActivity.java:303)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5610)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22265)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
```

Manifest premission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
```

I even found this [app](https://github.com/Nirvan101/cameraExample5) to do the same task, but when running it ... The app crashed as well

crash log

```
    --------- beginning of crash
09-12 23:50:32.410 24201-24201/com.example.nirvan.cameraexample3 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.nirvan.cameraexample3, PID: 24201
    android.os.FileUriExposedException: file:///storage/emulated/0/Pictures/20180912_235032.jpg exposed beyond app through ClipData.Item.getUri()
        at android.os.StrictMode.onFileUriExposed(StrictMode.java:1799)
        at android.net.Uri.checkFileUriExposed(Uri.java:2346)
        at android.content.ClipData.prepareToLeaveProcess(ClipData.java:832)
        at android.content.Intent.prepareToLeaveProcess(Intent.java:8909)
        at android.content.Intent.prepareToLeaveProcess(Intent.java:8894)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1517)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4224)
        at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityJB.startActivityForResult(BaseFragmentActivityJB.java:48)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:75)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4183)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:871)
        at com.example.nirvan.cameraexample3.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:52)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5610)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22265)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
```

any help on what I am missing or what I am doing wrong

Answer (score 1):

The first crash-  the user turned off your camera permission.  Or possibly the camera permission of the camera app.  You can check for your permissions by running checkPermission, but there's no way to stop them (nor should there be).

Comment: I added the camera permission in mainfest ...     <uses-permission 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />

Comment: @Mustafa That doesn't mean it was granted.  Android does runtime permissions now-  you can turn off some permissions even if its in the manifest.

Comment: added code to grant permission, but it still crashes!